# What does a dollar sign mean in a sitecore config file

Tags: sitecore

I have a setting in my Sitecore config file like the below.  What is the dollar sign used for?

```xml
<setting name="MediaFolder" value="$(mediaFolder)"/>
```

Comment: It basically indicates a variable replacement. In this case replace with the location of the media folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that variable with that name is used, e.g.:

```xml
<sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/upload" />
```

You can find few variables at the beginning of your Sitecore.config file:

```xml
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />
<sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/upload" />
<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp" />
```

You can use them later in the config files this way:

```xml
<DumpFile>$(dataFolder)/diagnostics/counters.{date}.{time}.{processid}.txt</DumpFile>

<setting name="MediaFolder" value="$(mediaFolder)" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `<DumpFile>$(dataFolder)/diagnostics/counters.{date}.{time}.{processid}.txt</DumpFile>`? I believe Sitecore variables can only be used in attributes, not in element bodies.

Answer (score 0):

$ means value of...

```
<setting name="MediaFolder" value="$(mediaFolder)" />
```

here $(mediaFolder) : value of mediaFolder variable.

Variable can be define:

```
<sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/data" />
```